# Http server is sleeping

Tags: raspbian

I have a simple http (no ssl) server running on raspbian written in dot net core (self contained app).

Currently it just presents a simple message.

The problem I'm facing is that it seems that the server is sleeping when idle.

First request takes up to 10 seconds to be answered.

Subsequent requests are immediate.

When server is on stanby for a period next request takes longer.

I tested requesting manually on telnet, the socket connects fast, processing the request is what is taking time.

Is there a configuration to keep it up and promptly all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a cron task that will run curl on the endpoint every so often to keep it "hot"?

Comment: Nice workarround!

Comment: @Edney Did this work for you? If so, please select this as an answer to your question.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually I didn't test it, didn't had time. But I will not accept this as an anwer as this is a "workarround" kinda like a "hack". I'm looking for a proper way to avoid the process sleeping. Sorry. Thanx for help!

Comment: In fact this _is_ the correct way of keeping a process "hot" in Linux.  In the case of the limited resources RPi, processes get swapped out of memory by other things that run normally and it takes some time to get it back and running.  By "pinging" it periodically you keep it in memory and ready to respond to requests.  I'm not clear what else you're looking for.

Comment: Is there a **configuration** to keep it up and promptly all the time?

Comment: I disagree, raspberry pi 3 has 1 Gb of memory, its far than enough, I run only the server, no concurrency. There must be a proper configuration to keep it responsive. One thing I though is that maybe this is an dot net core issue, not a raspberry, or linux issue. For example I have a cheap router that runs linux on MIPS (very limited in resources), it is always ready, not even a second lag!

Comment: By the way, I'll stop being a jerk and test it this weekend, if it works out I'll mark it as an answer!

Comment: As I suspected, the problem was not at all related to raspberry. I don't know why, but cross compiling it is what caused the problem, I uploaded the project files and compiled it in raspberry. No problem anymore! That is, first ssl handshake can take up to 5 seconds (probably to generate key pairs ?).